# Material slide toggle to show button/content

Tags: angular, material-ui

I am new to Angular. I am building a website that would compile test questions which should be entered in LaTeX format with image/gif/audio/video/hybrid files upload features from the device. Since I can't find a good text editor, I'm forced to create a separate button for other file types with a slide toggle from Angular [Material UI](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview). But I couldn't find the proper solution to show the button via sliding toggle.

[image: Example for using slide toggle to show button or other features]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to find? on the page you linked there's a very simple example: `<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>`

Comment: @devmiles.com I edited the question and added an excellent example with a gif.  I am trying to find such a feature in the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a expansion-panel with a slide-toogle disabled that you force opacity to 1

```
  <mat-expansion-panel #pannel >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header  >
      <mat-panel-title>
      <mat-slide-toggle 
             [style.opacity]="1" 
             [disabled]="true"
             [ngModel]="pannel.expanded" >Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>

      </mat-panel-title>
      
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9om1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)